# JQgrid using onPaging to change the URL values for Ajax call ...using existing onPaging

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Sir

In JQGrid  would like to change the 'Page', startpg, endpg, ...arguments in the URL to an ajajx call and fetch the next set of records & page.

```
 ex: -  URL url:'Data.jsp?&sord=asc&page=1&startpg=25&endpg=35'
```

I would like to use the existing `next Page/ last Page icons` from the marked events in the image to request/respond an servlet to fetch the data accordingly.

I know that using 'setGridParam' & trigger('reloadGrid') would modify the  existing values with new values on the request to load the data to the grid.

How can i call the setGridParam' & trigger('reloadGrid')  by the related icons  from the page

[image]
regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Onpaging event to grid config

```
$("#your_grid").jqGrid({
    url: 'your url",
        .....
    onPaging: function (pgButton) {
       alert(pgButton);// prev or next
          // Do what ever
     $('#your_grid').getGridParam('page')
   },
   .....
});
```